# encoding are set to "ISO-8859-1" can display Chinese characters

Tags: jsp, servlets, encoding

I am working on a MVC web app. I have a question about how this app displays Chinese characters even all page's encoding are set to "ISO-8859-1"? I thought ISO-8859-1 does not support Chinese characters.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ISO-8859-1 does indeed not support it. The webapp is either using HTML entities (e.g. `中` is presented as `&#20013;` (decimal) or `&#x4e2d;` (hexadecimal)), or is actually setting the UTF-8 in the content type response header.

To check if it's using HTML entities or not, view the generated HTML source of the page in browser by rightclick and *View Source*. To check if the content type response header  indicates UTF-8 encoding, press F12 in Chrome/Firebug/IE9 and check Net(work) section of the web developer toolset.

[image]